# jQuery button primary & secondary

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button

I am using jQuery button in my project, I need to display primary button in orange color and secondary button in grey color; but for me both buttons are in the same color grey. I am using following code:

```
$(function() {

        $( "button, input:submit").button({ icons: {primary:'ui-icon-gear',secondary:'ui-icon-triangle-1-s'} });

    });
```

Comment: Where are you defining the button's colors?

Answer (score 1):

the "primary" and "secondary" arguments are for putting multiple icons on the same button.

To style different buttons differently, you'll need to call `button()` separately on them. Something like:

```
$('#main_button').button({icons: {primary:'ui-icon-gear'} });
$('#other_button').button({icons: {primary:'other-icon'} });
```

Edit: I don't see how you'd set the background color with the button() call. Maybe try something like this:

```
#other_button { background-color: orange;}
#other_button:hover { background-color: darker-orange;}
```

Comment: its changing my button icons but i need to change my button background color

Comment: my primary need to change to orange color and secondary button background color need to change to grey color

Comment: wouldn't you do that with css?

Comment: it will change the font color not background color.

Comment: @alan ,do you want to differentiate between mouseover and mouseout.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a secondary button style by go going to the [theme roller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) , customizing the button to the correct background color then download the custom package.  Add the background to the project and add a custom css style to the button.

```
.custom-button
{
    background: #f47d20 url(../content/images/ui-bg_glass_75_f47d20_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x !important;
}
```